# Asp.net MVC retrieve many images from remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, image-processing, file-io

I user Asp.Net MVC 4 with frameword 4.0
I use this code in my controller for retrieve image from remote server:

```
private List<Imagenes> Galeria(bool Remoto, string Directorio){
        string path = string.Empty;
        DirectoryInfo dir = null;
        List<Imagenes> listImagenes = new List<Imagenes>();
        path = Directorio;
        dir = new DirectoryInfo(Directorio);           
        FileInfo[] fileList = dir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        var fileQuery = from file in fileList
                        where ((file.Extension.ToUpper() == ".JPG") ||
                               (file.Extension.ToUpper() == ".PNG") ||
                               (file.Extension.ToUpper() == ".GIF") ||
                               (file.Extension.ToUpper() == ".JPEG"))
                        orderby file.Name
                        select file;

        foreach (var file in fileQuery)
        {
            var b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path + file.Name);                
            listImagenes.Add(new Imagenes(Convert.ToBase64String(b)));
        }
        return listImagenes;
    }

public class Imagenes
{
    public string imagen { get; set; }
    public Imagenes(string sImagen)
    {
        imagen = sImagen;
    }
}
```

This works if the number of images in the directory is 5, if they are more than 5  I get out of memory exception.
How I can resolve this problem? if in the remote directory i have more than 30 images

Comment: Which line causes the exception?

Comment: @MikeG in var b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path + file.Name);

Answer (score 0):

To avoid retrieving all files from the get-go, try this:

```
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).
        Where( f => 
               f.Extension.ToUpper() == ".JPG" || 
               f.Extension.ToUpper() == ".PNG" || 
               f.Extension.ToUpper() == ".GIF" || 
               f.Extension.ToUpper() == ".JPEG").
        ToArray<FileInfo>();
```

Furthermore, you should clear your Byte array before your next file iteration:

```
        Array.Resize<byte>(ref b, 0);
```